# Get Selected Range in Codemirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

If i select a piece of range in my codemirror editor with say shift+up/down/left/right , is there a way to get the co-ordinates of the piece of text selected ? Like the line num for start/end, the char positions relative to lines and also to document ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`codemirror.getCursor(true)` will get you the start of the selection. 
`codemirror.getCursor(false)` will get you the end of the selection.

Answer (score 5):

I attach the function to the editor instance after creating it e.g.

```js
editor.getSelectedRange = function() {
  return { from: editor.getCursor(true), to: editor.getCursor(false) };
};
```

to match the standard `getSelection` method. If you're dealing with a lot of editor instances you'll have to add it to each though, the instances are just individual Objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it takes a boolean any more. The documentation now says `getCursor(?start: string)`, where `start` is "head", "start", or "end" (with "head" as the default).

Comment: You're absolutely right: doc.getCursor(?start: string) → {line, ch}
Retrieve one end of the primary selection. start is an optional string indicating which end of the selection to return. It may be "from", "to", "head" (the side of the selection that moves when you press shift+arrow), or "anchor" (the fixed side of the selection). Omitting the argument is the same as passing "head". A {line, ch} object will be returned.